# creating hidden field as extension in razor (worked in IE not in Mozilla)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've created a hidden field as an extension, it worked nice in Internet explorer but when I wanted it to execute in chrome or mozilla it didnot support...

```
public static MvcHtmlString hiddenText(this HtmlHelper helper, string Text)
{
    var tag = new TagBuilder("input");
    tag.MergeAttribute("id", "hid");
    tag.MergeAttribute("name", Text);
    tag.MergeAttribute("value", Text);
    return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString())
}
```

Is there any solution so that the code i write will work in mozilla or chrome..
Thank you..

Comment: Why are people so inclined to re-write this sort of thing? Html.Hidden works EXACTLY as you require.. why re-invent the wheel?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to specify the input type.

```
tag.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
```

On a side note, you do realise there's already built in helpers that allow you to create hidden fields?

```
@Html.Hidden()

@Html.HiddenFor()
```